How to pass '$' => Special Character as argument for makefile
I tried to pass password for postgres that is used in go scrip which is passed throug a makefile
My password contains '$' character=> the makefile doesnt recognize it a character.
I tried using escape character '$$' => this doesn't work too
pwsd:=$1

run:
    @echo "Password passed: ${pwsd}"
    @go run ./cmd/web ${pwsd}

input:
make run pwsd="passwd$"
output:
Password passed: passwd

input:
make run pwsd="passwd$$"
output:
Password passed: passwdpwsd=passwd$

expected:
Password passed: passwd$


Which make are you using, and which shell are you launching it from? A variation on your makefile that omits the go run produces your expected output for me with command make run pwsd="passwd$".  That's with Bash 4.4.20 and GNU make 4.2.1.

Note also that the pwsd:=$1 almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does.

You need to suppress parameter expansion. Hence, make run 'pwsd=passwd$$' or make run pwsd=passwd\$\$, depending on your stylistic preferences.

@user1934428 => Thank man, this worked

First, when debugging makefiles you should never add the @ prefix to your recipe.  This is like running your compiler with the output sent to /dev/null.
You have to first understand that $ is special to the shell: it introduces a shell variable.  So you have to escape the $ from the shell first of all.  Using double-quotes doesn't do that: shell variables are expanded inside double-quotes:
foo=bar
echo "$foo"

shows bar, not $foo.  If you want to ensure that a string containing $ is not expanded by the shell, you should use single quotes:
foo=bar
echo '$foo'

This will show $foo.  So if you want the shell to see a string containing a dollar sign you need to both (a) invoke make with the value properly quoted, and (b) use proper escaping quotes in your recipe.  For example:
run:
        @echo 'Password passed: ${pwsd}'
        go run ./cmd/web '${pwsd}'

Then if you run make pwsd='foo$bar' the result will be:
Password passed: foo$bar
go run ./cmd/web 'foo$bar'

I should point out this will fail if your password can contain single-quotes.  If you want to support this, you'll have to be extra-fancy; something like this:
quoted_pwsd = '$(subst ','"'"',$(pwsd))'
run:
        @echo Password passed: ${quoted_pwsd}
        go run ./cmd/web ${quoted_pwsd}

but you have to be careful where you use this.
